# How can I change the displayed tab width in JavaFX with RichTextFX?

Tags: java, javafx, richtextfx

I'm writing a text editor in JavaFX with the RichTextFX library and when I write a tab it has a width of 8. How can I change this **without** replacing the tab with e.g. 4 whitespaces?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
Nodes.addInputMap(this.codeArea, InputMap.consume(EventPattern.keyPressed(KeyCode.TAB), e -> {
    this.codeArea.replaceSelection("    ");
}));
```

It replaces a tab with 4 whitespaces but how can I make that one tab is displayed with a width of 4 whitespaces?

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what version of JavaFX you are using.  This https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8130738 was implemented in JavaFX 14.

See: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html#tabSizeProperty

and: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text

Comment: How do i get the textflow of the code area? i tried this but its not working:
-fx-tab-size: 8px;
So i ended up increasing the font size and scaling the actual component for a smaller tab.

Comment: @JpSilver check the docs for the CSS property, it takes an integer only.  The number of "spaces" in a Tab.

Comment: Thank you good sir. Its working now. I thought it had to be px because of intellij's intellisence haha, seems obvious now, witch it actually is. Thank you!